# JNDI access with Tomcat 7 and embedded HornetQ

Tags: spring, tomcat, jndi, hornetq

I set up a new project with Tomcat 7.0 and an embedded HornetQ JMS server.
I used these 2 tutorials to help me:

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/spring-3-hornetq-21-integration.html
- http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2010/08/hornetq-jms-integration-with-tomcat.html

But as it is mentioned in the tutos, the Tomcat JNDI repository is readonly (cannot find a way to write) and I configured a "separated" JNDI used by HornetQ, the messaging works, but Tomcat cannot access it.

Normally, in my other projects using Tomcat, I defined the datasource as a global resource in the server.xml and I map it in the context.xml. doing this, the definition of the datasource (jdbc url, credentials, etc...) are outside the application and can be managed by environment (dev, test, prod, ...) but I cannot find a way to do it with the other JNDI.

Currently, the datasource is defined in my application with an external property file for the parameters but I am not really satisfied with this solution.

Here is my Spring configuration:

```
<!-- enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- enable transaction demarcation with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${URL}" />
    <property name="username" value="${user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />

    <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- HornetQ config -->
<bean name="namingServerImpl" class="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl" init-method= "start" destroy-method="stop" >
<!-- configure HornetQ JNDI server not to use an existing JNDI service if available -->
    <property name="useGlobalService" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean name="namingServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="namingInfo" ref="namingServerImpl" />
    <property name="port" value="1099" />
    <property name="bindAddress" value="localhost" />
    <property name="rmiPort" value="1098" />
    <property name="rmiBindAddress" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<bean name="mbeanServer" class="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" factory-method="getPlatformMBeanServer" />

<bean name="fileConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.core.config.impl.FileConfiguration"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" />

<bean name="hornetQSecurityManagerImpl" class="org.hornetq.spi.core.security.HornetQSecurityManagerImpl" />

<!-- The core server -->
<bean name="hornetQServerImpl" class="org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="fileConfiguration" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="mbeanServer" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="hornetQSecurityManagerImpl" />
</bean>

<!-- The JMS server -->
<bean name="jmsServerManagerImpl" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="namingServer">
    <constructor-arg ref="hornetQServerImpl" />
</bean>

<!-- to use HornetQ messaging service through Spring we can either create a connection factory, or lookup one from JNDI -->
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="boolean" value="false"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="org.hornetq.integration.transports.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                    <entry key="port" value="5445"></entry>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="notificationsQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" depends-on="jmsServerManagerImpl">
 <property name="jndiName">
  <value>/queue/Notifications</value>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="inVMConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" depends-on="jmsServerManagerImpl">
 <property name="jndiName">
  <value>/ConnectionFactory</value>
 </property>
</bean>
```

How can I managed it in a better way, I mean, define the datasource on the server side as usual? Is there a configuration to tell Tomcat to use the external JNDI I defined or create a read/write repo?